# golang server upload file response net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: file-upload, upload, go, response

I am uploading a small audio file to server using DART  + golang. Everything kinda works fine, until I POST and go doesn't return anything. I would like to return filename so I can change the label text on the input.

1) GOLANG:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"
)

http.HandleFunc("/upload", webUploadHandler)

[...] 

func webUploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

   file, header, err := r.FormFile("file") // the FormFile function takes in the POST input id file
   defer file.Close()

   if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
      return
   }

   out, err := os.Create("/tmp/uploadedfile")

   if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unable to create the file for writing. Check your write access privilege")
      return
   }


   defer out.Close()

   // write the content from POST to the file
   _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
   }

   fmt.Fprintf(w,"File uploaded successfully : ")
   fmt.Fprintf(w, header.Filename)

}
```

2) DART response, alert

`window.alert("upload complete");`
works

3) ERROR in Chromium Console:

```
POST http://localhost:9999/upload net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I'm quite new to GOLANG so any help will me much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is not a bug in your code but most probably a bug in Chromium, does it happen in other browser/when you try ```curl```?

Comment: same in Chrome. in FF i get: 
Request URL:  http://localhost:9999/upload
Request Method:  POST
Status Code:

Comment: how could I get the filename in the response? and what is the purpose of the last 2 lines, `Fprintf` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error in the code above:

```
defer file.Close()
```

was before checking

```
if err != nil
```

-- UPDATE

and missing part 2, in DART:

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
```